# Show output in built in terminal instead of pop-up in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I need to use Visual Studio instead of Rider and I'm used to seeing the terminal output in the same screen at the bottom (see screen shot below).

When I run a program in Visual Studio the terminal is a pop up, I haven't found anyway to get the output as an integrated tab in Visual Studio, is there anyway to do that?

[Rider terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxdN3.png)

Comment: Note that Visual Studio is not the same as VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022 you can access the integrated terminal by using:

View > Terminal

Comment: That does not answer Smeagol's question.